# Edit single lines in textfile

Tags: c#, vb.net

Imagine, you are confronted with a big textfile, for example HTML, and only want to edit one line of code in this file.
The standard approach would be to first read everthing and then write everthing, including the changed text, back to a separate file, which would not be very efficient in this usecase.

I want to use a similar approach to open a file in the Editor, find the line you need and then edit this specific line.

Is there any FileIO that allows actual editing/replacing in stead of plain append or create?

EDIT:
What I have in my mind so far is exactly the example that Rahul Singh gave below.
But as mentioned, if I think about this approach it doesn't seem very efficient if you just want to edit one or even a few lines. In my actual problem where the question came from, the file is a HTML file in which want to insert a additional table row. But I think this use-case also is interesting to all files that contains plain text

Comment: If you aren't writing the exact same number of bytes you want to replace, no, there is no such way. That's simply not how files work, regardless of language or framework used.

Comment: Do you want an API or whatever that allows you to do such as `theTextFile.Append("ADDITIONAL_TABLE_ROW", INDEX_TO_START);` and then just inserts the contents into the index specified, *NOT* writing all the contents? I don't think there's any...

Comment: Have you tried reading and writing everything in your usecase?  Sounds like optimising prematurely.

Comment: I tried and am using this approach at current, but I only have to handle small file at present. I cant imagine that writing the whole file anew if you only want to change a few lines in a big peace file can be pretty efficient. If you write a letter with a pen and recognise you wrote a word wrong, do you really write the whole letter anew or just use some ink eraser for that word^^

Comment: @suzi exactly some API like this was what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT.It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" 
>   HTML files.

For example this code fix all hrefs in HTML file:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);    //FixLink() is your custom method
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly please share what you have tried so far, as we dont have any idea upon data that your textFile contains,
First read through out the file in streamreader and store it into string then do string.replace and do the editing, you could also use the split options and by check it by contains function do the editing.
and you can always go by XSLT options but for that you need to use XPath to select